# Where can I create a Dialogflow action from the Google Actions Console?

Tags: webhooks, google-home

Every tutorial I found online for creating a Google action involved creating a new action in the Google actions console which redirected to a Dialogflow project. More specifically, I followed this video by Fireship:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZY_in9oAjA&t=260s

However, when I opened the Google actions console and created a new project, there wasn't an option to create a new action.[image: This is the page I was met with.]

How do I create a Google action from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video you were following is outdated. From the screen you reached, you can use the Actions Builder tool that is now included in the Console. For more details on this, check out the updated [Build Actions codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-builder-1).